# OpenCV LabView Copy Image to a bigger one

Tags: c++, opencv, labview

I have a big problem since some days. I have created in LabView an empty Image with the size 4096x4096 and want to copy a smaller Image to it in OpenCV.
As a result I will get everytime a black image.

```
Mat imgIn = Mat(SizeX, SizeY, CV_16U, &image[0]);          // Small pic
Mat imOut = Mat(4096, 4096, CV_16U, &imgOut[0]);

imgIn.copyTo(imOut(Rect(500, 500, imgIn.size().width, imgIn.size().height)));

for(int i = 0;i < 4096;i++){
    for(int j = 0;j < 4096;j++){

         if((imOut.data[i,j])>300) *test += 1;
         *imgOut++ = imOut.data[i,j];
    } 
}
```

Here my new VI from Labview:

[image]

My result:

[image]

Update: after the updated code:

```
Mat imgIn = Mat(SizeX, SizeY, CV_16U, &image[0]);          // Small pic
Mat imOut = Mat(4096, 4096, CV_16U, &imgOut[0]);

imgIn.copyTo(imOut(Rect(500, 500, imgIn.size().width, imgIn.size().height)));
```

Pic:

[image]

Update 2 Code:

```
// --- Dll entry point ---
 BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, 
                   DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, 
                   LPVOID lpReserved
                 )
{
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hModule);
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpReserved);
switch (ul_reason_for_call)
{
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    break;
}
return TRUE;
}


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif  /* __cplusplus */


__declspec(dllexport) INT myDoSomething(unsigned int *test, unsigned short *image, int SizeX, int SizeY, unsigned short *imgOut){

// Alloc Memory
Mat imgIn = Mat(SizeX, SizeY, CV_16U, &image[0]);          // Small pic
Mat imOut = Mat(4096, 4096, CV_16U, &imgOut[0]);           // Big pic

imgIn.copyTo(imOut(Rect(1000, 1000, imgIn.size().width, imgIn.size().height)));
```

Comment: The `copyTo` code is correct. Can you try changing `imOut.data[i,j]` to `imOut.at<ushort>(i,j)` ? What are `imgOut` and `test`?

Comment: Still no change, but I have tried another method which saves computation time and is easier. The only problem is that now the image is shown strange.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], or we can only guess ;D

Comment: Try `CV_16S` instead of `CV_16U`

Comment: can you provide also `image` and `imgOut`?

Comment: I suspect that the problem is elsewhere. Please double check that your images are single channel, and of type CV_16U

Comment: Thanks, but I have checked already everything, I suspect that it has s.th. to do with alignment of the images (2 or 4 byte).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved:

OpenCV treats Matrices not as in LabView like X,Y (column, row), but as row,column!!

```
Mat imgIn = Mat(SizeY, SizeX, CV_16UC1, &image[0]);
```